# Agg count with range count

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, aggregation

My doc look like

```
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "33",
}
```

I would like to have the number of userId who have more than

100 docs
between 50 and 100 docs
less than 100 docs
I try to use different aggregation but I don't know how to make range aggregation on the count of another aggregation

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) along with [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html), to segregate the UserId based on their doc count

In the below example, consider 5 documents of `"UserId":"33"`, 3 documents of "UserId":"34" and 1 document of `"UserId":"35"`. Now the search query will segregate the UserId based on

1. Count of users having doc count less than or equal to 2
2. Count of users having doc count between 2 and 4
3. Count of users having doc count greater than or equal to 4

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "34"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "34"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "34"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "33"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "33"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "33"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "33"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "33"
}
{
      "path": "/foo/bar",
      "userId" : "35"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "userId_lessThanEqualTo2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "less_than_2": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.the_doc_count < 2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "userId_btw2-4": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "less_than_4": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.the_doc_count >= 2 && params.the_doc_count < 4"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "userId_greaterThanEqualTo4": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "greater_than_4": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.the_doc_count >= 4"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "aggregations": {
    "userId_btw2-4": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "34",
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    "userId_greaterThanEqualTo4": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "33",
          "doc_count": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    "userId_lessThanEqualTo2": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "35",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @user2478384 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @user2478384 Welcome to Stackoverflow !! If the answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to accept the answer. You can accept the answer, by clicking on the check mark beside the answer :-)

Comment: @user2478384 can you please reply back to my previous comments ?

Answer (score 0):

tanks for your help.
I try it and the search result is :

```
"aggregations": {
    "userId_btw2-4": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 2125,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2482161,
      "buckets": []
    },
    "userId_greaterThanEqualTo4": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 2125,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2482138,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "804ba398-e512-4e43-a289-3e63483baabd",
          "doc_count" : 13914
        },
        {
          "key" : "de0ce908-7172-4be7-8e3e-181d94fb0571",
          "doc_count" : 8561
        },
        {
          "key" : "03670858-cb0b-4ca5-ae5a-07e92b12905f",
          "doc_count" : 4918
        },
        {
          "key" : "25a17282-2eb0-4a1f-8fdd-b0eef083af25",
          "doc_count" : 4847
        },
        {
          "key" : "c096169d-0bb3-42d2-8c24-92fa15754339",
          "doc_count" : 4265
        },
        {
          "key" : "9ff15fdc-2aa3-49a6-8422-4d7137f434ae",
          "doc_count" : 4159
        },
        {
          "key" : "ce77b5c0-e858-47a6-8598-879d78124857",
          "doc_count" : 3730
        },
        {
          "key" : "171bf337-8c19-4180-ba21-2ec9e72e380f",
          "doc_count" : 3513
        },
        {
          "key" : "745dd8e0-a021-4c91-abd8-2193e1805fd0",
          "doc_count" : 3245
        },
        {
          "key" : "e6645d55-a411-44c3-82db-1a5be1534e5e",
          "doc_count" : 3051
        }
      ]
    },
    "userId_lessThanEqualTo2": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 2125,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2482161,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
```